# EF/LINQ : Find() operation

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the current user data row. But, when I execute this code

```
MNDataContext _db = new MNDataContext();
var nm = User.Identity.Name;
var id = (int)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
var slct = _db.Utilisateurs.Find((int)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey);
```

I'm getting `null` as a value on the `var slct` line. This is weird because the debugger indicates that nm and id have their right values but the last one isn't getting the right object value.

MNDataContext class

```
public class MNDataContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<UtilisateurModel> Utilisateurs { get; set; }
}
```

Utilisateur's primary key:

```
[Key]         
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]         
[Display(Name = "Identifiant")]         
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What does `(int)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey` evaluate to ?

Comment: @Ofiris, it evaluates to `1`.

Comment: What does `Utilisateurs` looks like? does it have `id` property?

Comment: @Ofiris, yes it have as a Prinmary Key `[Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display(Name = "Identifiant")]
        public int UserId { get; set; }`

Comment: You might want to add that info it to your question, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try it like this?

```
MNDataContext _db = new MonitoringNDataContext();
var nm = User.Identity.Name;
var id = (int)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
UtilisateurModel slct = _db.Utilisateurs.Find(id);
```

Is `slct` still null? What value does `id` have?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess... You are doing a find of int where it expects an object. Try something like this

```
MNDataContext _db = new MonitoringNDataContext();
var nm = User.Identity.Name;
var id = (int)Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey;
UtilisateurModel slct = _db.Utilisateurs.Find(x=>x.Id=id);
```