# Downgrade from EF6 to EF5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Does EF6 not work with ASP.NET MVC 4? I've tried to downgrade to EF5. But when I run my web app. I'm getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And when I was using EF6 I was getting a NULL value on LINQ operations. [For more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323712/ef-linq-find-operation/22323944?noredirect=1#comment33924735_22323944).

How do I fix this please?